# Apache + php-fpm vs Nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, apache, performance, nginx

I have a wallpaper website (almost all traffic goes to images). I use the following apps to serve.

> apache2 + php5.3 + CGI/FastCGI

I have recently read that Nginx is faster than Apache. Also, many people advise using php-fpm. Do you recommend me to move my website to

> Nginx+php-fpm

or just make

> apache2 + php-fpm?

Comment: On the Internet, I could not find performances difference between Nginx+php-fpm and apache2 + php-fpm.

Comment: What performance problems are you having with apache? You'd get a much larger performance boost from php7.x upgrade over a web server change.

Comment: Good point, I'll upgrade to php7. Thanks for your advice @mkaatman

Comment: But still I want to know is Nginx+php-fpm faster than apache2 + php-fpm?

Comment: I need to decide whether to upgrade the current server or just configure it for the best performance

Comment: It really depends where your bottleneck is. If PHP is doing 99% of the work, there won't be much difference between the two. If the web server is doing 99% of the work then you might depending on circumstances. Blindly switching because one might be faster without having any performance issues seems silly.

Comment: I gotta disagree @mkaatman 
Although I agree with your conclusion, there definitely is a difference in performance of apache and nginx. Both have their strongsuits and their weaknesses but in general: If PHP has to do a lot of work Apache will actually be faster because mod_php is a part of the Apache itself and is really good integrated. The additional (f)cgi takes some time to when using Nginx and thus making it slower on PHP-heavy applications. Do you only want to serve a lot of static data (like images) you are better of with NGINX, because if excells on static content.

Comment: Yes, most of the traffic serves to images.

Comment: from my previous test on small vps (1 core & 1 GB memory), apache with php7 fpm (with opcache) faster about 50-100% than nginx with php7 fpm also with opcache.and faster about 200-300% than apache with mod php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There definitely is a difference in performance of Apache and NGINX.**

Both have their strongsuits and their weaknesses but in general:

If PHP has to do a lot of work Apache will actually be faster because mod_php is a part of the Apache itself and is really good integrated.

The additional (f)cgi takes some time too when using Nginx and thus making it slower on PHP-heavy applications.

**Conclusion**

Do you only want to serve a lot of static data (like images) you are better of with NGINX, because if excells on static content.

--> In your case I'd go with NGINX...don't forget to make good use of NGINX' caching-mechanisms!